# Compact, simple calculator made with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

```
num1 = int(input("What is your first number you would like me to calculate?(not a decimal)"))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number you would like me to calculate?(not a decimal)"))
calculation = input("How would you like me to calculate this?")

def add():
  if calculation in ["+", "add", "addition"]:
    answer = num1 + num2
    print(answer)

def subtract():
  if calculation in ["-", "subtract", "subtraction"]:
    answer = num1 - num2
    print(answer)

def divide():
  if calculation in ["/", "divide", "division"]:
    answer = num1 / num2
    print(answer)

def multiply():
  if calculation in ["x", "X", "*", "multiply", "multiplication"]:
    answer = num1 * num2
    print(answer)

add()
subtract()
divide()
multiply()
```

Is there a way I could make an error if a number and/or an operator was not pressed? (a letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making errors appear in your program as an output is known as 'Error Handling'. For this you need to know all the [types of errors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) there are in python. Since you seem like a beginner it would be okay for you to memorize some off the most used one's at least. Ideally you would want to know the ZeroDivisionError, ValueError and SyntaxError.

When implementing the error handling in your code you need to use try, except and else statements. This works in three steps:

- Try : This part tries to execute a certain piece of code.
- Except : This part is run only when and error occurs in the try
  statement.
- Else : This part runs if no error occurs in the try statement.

Here is the a sample code that improves the input section of your program:

```
# Simple Calculator

# Operator set
operator_set = set(["+", "add", "addition",
            "-", "subtract", "subtraction",
            "/", "divide", "division",
            "x", "*", "multiply", "multiplication"])

def User_input():
    """Prompt user input and handle errors"""
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            num1 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
            calculation = input("How would you like t calulate this?\n").lower()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error : {}".format(str(e)))

        else:
            if calculation in operator_set:
                break;
            else:
                print("Please re-enter a valid operator!")

    return num1, num2, calculation
```

Improvements made:

1.Comments and Docstrings - They make your program easier to understand and make it more readable to other programmers as well.

A Docstring is:

`def User_input():
     """Prompt user input and handle errors"""`

The """Data within these triple inverted commas define a functions process(what it does)"""

A comment is:

`# Operator set`

This gives a brief 'comment' on what that line of code does.

---

2. Added a new function for validating user input. Within this function is where the users input is validated and returned. **Validation is the process of ensuring that a program operates on clean, correct and useful data.** It useful to remember that in future programs as well. Here i have used try except and else statements for validation.

`except Exception as e:` This line means that if **any error** occurs, **assign that error to e** This is used to catch almost all errors without specifically mentioning them. You can individually write an exception statement for each error but the is the easy way out.

---

3. Used a set to check if users operator was valid. Again another form of validation used here to make sure user inputs only valid operators.

`calculation = input("How would you like t calculate this?\n").lower()` The `.lower()` means that the users input is automatically converted to lower case. DO keep in mind that this is only for letters not symbols and numbers. This means even if the user inputs "ADD" the returned value will be "add", which is as we need in the operator set. To check whether this was in the operator set we used a simple if condition.

---

4. Finally a while loop used to keep asking the user's input until valid input has been entered. This is pretty straight-forward and can be used in several cases.

---

**There are still more improvements but these are the error handling exceptions that you requested for.**

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what you were hoping for from a code review, but you did mention *compact* in the title, so I will show one way the code could be made even more compact.

**Collapse (almost) Duplicate Code**

The heart of your code is 4 functions that are almost identical.  The below example exploits the commonality and places the parts that are unique to each function into a table.  The table is then accessed to run the calculator.

```
operations = (
    (('+', 'add', 'addition'), lambda n: n[0] + n[1]),
    (('-', 'subtract', 'subtraction'), lambda n: n[0] - n[1]),
    (('/', 'divide', 'division'), lambda n: n[0] / n[1]),
    (('x', 'X', '*', 'multiply', 'multiplication'), lambda n: n[0] * n[1]),
)
```

This table defines 4 entries (one for each operation).  Each entry consists of the keywords for the operation, and  a `lambda` which will perform the calculation.

**What's a `lamdba`?**

A `lambda` is a function, that takes one parameter, and consists of a single expression which is the value returned.  In addition they have no name, so when they are defined, the result of the definition needs to be stored somehow for later use.  In this case we store them as the second element of each entry in our table.

**Run the Calculator**

```
for op in operations:
    if calculation in op[0]:
        print(op[1](nums))
```

There are three lines of code here.

1. Loop through the table of operations
2. If the `calculation` is in the operation, then...
3. Call the lambda defined for this operation, and print the result

**Calling the `lambda`**

That third line in the calculation loop could use some explanation.  From the inside out, we first have

```
op[1]
```

This accesses the second element of the operation defined in the operations table.  The element happens to be our `lambda`.  IE. it is a function.  As such we can call that function, recalling that it takes one parameter:

```
op[1](nums)
```

But how can we pass one parameter when we need two for our calculation?

We can combine the two parameters into a single `tuple`.

```
nums = (num1, num2)
```

**Complete Calculator:**

```
num1 = float(input("What is your first number you would like me to calculate? "))
num2 = float(input("What is your second number you would like me to calculate? "))
nums = (num1, num2)
calculation = input('How would you like me to calculate this? ')

operations = (
    (('+', 'add', 'addition'), lambda n: n[0] + n[1]),
    (('-', 'subtract', 'subtraction'), lambda n: n[0] - n[1]),
    (('/', 'divide', 'division'), lambda n: n[0] / n[1]),
    (('x', 'X', '*', 'multiply', 'multiplication'), lambda n: n[0] * n[1]),
)
for op in operations:
    if calculation in op[0]:
        print(op[1](nums))
```